# Switching tmux zoom between panes without zooming out

Tags: tmux

After zooming in to a tmux pane, I'd like to zoom in on another pane (preferably the next) without zooming out first.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this line to your .tmux.conf file

```
bind -r a select-pane -t .+1 \;  resize-pane -Z
```

Now press (<kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>) will loop through current window's panes (`select-pane -t .+1`) and zooming them (`resize-pane -Z`) , after pressing the <kbd>prefix</kbd> key just once , you can press <kbd>a</kbd> again and again to loop through panes because of the `-r` option (`bind -r a`).

You have the freedom to change the <kbd>a</kbd> key to another one.

Comment: It works. Thanks! Is there a way to do it without configuration changes?

Comment: No , You can't (tmux 1.8) , Don't be afraid of .tmux.conf that what will make you use tmux very efficient with your needs

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Exactly what I'm looking for.

What I have configured for myself, is to bind `]` to `+1`, and `[` to `-`, so I can cycle through the panes in both directions.

Comment: some of the panes' outputs scroll up bit by bit after each switching. (for common things which can't adapt to a resize properly like ls, etc. unlike btop, top, htop etc which all work fine)